# When to use __gc for classes and structs?

Tags: class, garbage-collection, c++-cli, interop, managed-c++

I am updating some old c++ code and am finding that many of the classes are defined as:

```
public __gc class NameOfClass{  }
```

I found a little bit of information about __gc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms384241%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), but it seems to only come up with information for VS 2003.  The MSDN documentation that came with my copy of VS 2005 indicates that __gc may not be in use anymore.

I'm a C# guy myself, so I want to make sure I don't make a mistake when updating this code.  Is garbage collecting automatic for c++ classes in .NET 2.0 and greater?  Or has the __gc keyword been replaced in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at C++ with managed extensions which was a brief and failed attempt to add clr functionality to cpp using some rather inventive syntax.  I believe from 2005 onward c++ cli was fully supported which is a full implementation of the clr in C++.  Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379603%28VS.80%29.aspx) for migrating advice from m.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The link gave me exactly what I needed: 
"In the original language definition, a reference class type is prefaced with the __gc keyword. In the revised language, the __gc keyword is replaced by one of two spaced keywords: refclass or refstruct. "

Answer (score 1):

It has been somewhat (possibly entirely) replaced; I believe it's still supported for BC, but there was a new mechanism introduced with VS2005 which made managed types more explicit. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

For reference, the big problem with the old syntax was that it added overloaded usage of standard C++ syntax, which was dependent on the underlying types, which was horribly confusing in code. The new syntax is much better for differentiating managed handles from unmanaged pointers.